# How to build properly micro service when it due to filesystem

Tags: node.js, rest, api, microservices

I have an API1 that calls API 2 to perform tasks such as:

1) Crop images, save images

This process takes long and of-course the call time-out.

Both API are built in Nodejs Rest API.

How to properly construct this process so I don't have timeouts?

Do I call the endpoint , and than call the endpoint somehow later to check again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of system where you could expect timeout because of long operation , you cloud be using aysnc operation AMQP (Advance message queue protocol).  Both the services/apps should work completely independent. Your service 1 drops the message in the queue and service 2 picks up the message to process. Once done it notifies the service 1.

You have to be mindful that REST/HTTP is the synchronous by nature and you need to know the implications. That means when your service 1 is requesting other service via HTTP to do something and waiting for it to complete you are actually blocking the thread. Although your client might be implementing the async http call but under the hood you are still waiting for the request to complete in synchronous manner and this kind of system is very hard to scale.

Another suggestion is to use serverless if you can. e.g. AWS lambda / Azure functions are generally very good at it . Basically you notify the serverless function to do some operation and you can wireup notification when they are done. But they have limitations of running only for couple of mins. Really depends if you have operation that can fit serverless in the picture.

Comment: amazing reply. thank you. But could you explain more on how it 'Once done it notifies the service 1.' How does service 1 find out about it?

Comment: Glad if it helped. You can use pub/sub with message queues (topics and subscription) . The interested service is listening to events. When service 1 put message in queue ["please do this event"] , service 2 is subscribed to event and gets notified. Once done service 2 drops the message ["i am done event"] and service 1 is subscribed to event and gets notified . This makes the service completely independent.

Comment: Aha, so that how you can also scale this process , by having multiple calls and everything is queued

Comment: depends how you design but your apis should be seperate services for it to scale. your one service keep on dropping messages in queue and other service will handle it asynchronously. even if your queue grows doesn't matter since your services will only process the message at the capacity they can handle

Comment: if your apis are in single project then rather calling other api to process you still drop the message in queue and write backend job to process it. your backend job would raise event once it's done.

Comment: To help me understand better. The user does an action to 'crop images', that actions get sent to my API(1) that send a MSG to RabbitMQ to crop images. API (2) picks up the quee and execute command to crop images, than on success it post to API (1) saying job done or post on RabbitMQ a new quee saying job done.

How do I meanwhile tell the user to a) we would get back to them when the job is done, or B) send a notification that job is done.

Comment: that's right.  to notify user you can keep them await and from ui keep polling the status of job from api1. or better way is to avoid poll and use web sockets to update ui. if the task takes too long then may be you can send email when job is done. really depends on your use case

Comment: your amazing!, will look into web sockets, as heard a lot about them but need to now understand how to implement one :)